# Spring Security OAuth2 (Google authorized redirect URI) - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 login (Google) to my REST api using Spring Boot. When im trying to get *http://localhost:8080/api/login/oauth2/code/google* (my Google authorized redirect URI) i'm getting exception message **Full authentication is required to access this resource.**
How can i disable Spring Security to get this URI from my api ? Without Spring Security it works.

My SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Profile("dev")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/sign-up").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/sign-in").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/refresh").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My JwtFilter.class

```
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

public JwtFilter(JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
    this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = jwtProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
    if (!((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getRequestURL().toString().endsWith("auth/refresh")) {
        try {
            if (token != null && jwtProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                Authentication authentication = jwtProvider.getAuthentication(token);
                if (authentication != null) {
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        } catch (JwtAuthenticationException e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("Access token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

}

My properties file

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: <id>
            client-secret: <secret>
```

Comment: I don't see any rule permitting access to that URL. (Note also that JWT support is available out-of-the-box in Spring Security; you should not be writing your own filter.)

Comment: How can i add this rule to this url ? If i add it in configure method with .antMatchers(...).permitAny() it doesnt work.